# Weird restart of Android application

Tags: android, savestate

It could be that I am misunderstanding how it should work but something weird is happening.

Our main Activity is "MainMenuActivity" from it we call a submenu.
From there the user chooses an option and gets some data and can then zoom in on that data.

So effectively we have a chain of A -> B -> C -> D

I then force the application to finish by calling the phone.
The logcat clearly shows that the application dies. I then get a timeout on the activity when it restarts it.
This is what the logcat looks like:

```
    10-21 14:42:06.018: I/ActivityManager(1156): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.applicat.meuchedet/.MenuScreenActivity (has extras) } from pid 22170
10-21 14:42:06.558: I/ActivityManager(1156): Displayed com.applicat.meuchedet/.MenuScreenActivity: +469ms
10-21 14:42:10.728: I/ActivityManager(1156): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.applicat.meuchedet/.PrescriptionsListScreen } from pid 22170
10-21 14:42:11.368: I/ActivityManager(1156): Displayed com.applicat.meuchedet/.PrescriptionsListScreen: +591ms
10-21 14:42:26.068: I/ActivityManager(1156): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.applicat.meuchedet/.MedicinePurchasesListScreen (has extras) } from pid 22170
10-21 14:42:26.758: I/ActivityManager(1156): Displayed com.applicat.meuchedet/.MedicinePurchasesListScreen: +624ms
10-21 14:43:11.288: I/ActivityManager(1156): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.applicat.meuchedet/.MainActivity bnds=[242,271][358,389] } from pid 21281
10-21 14:43:42.288: I/ActivityManager(1156): Process com.applicat.meuchedet (pid 22170) has died.
10-21 14:43:56.948: I/ActivityManager(1156): Start proc com.applicat.meuchedet for activity com.applicat.meuchedet/.MedicinePurchasesListScreen: pid=22483 uid=10106 gids={3003}
10-21 14:43:58.188: W/ActivityManager(1156):   Force finishing activity com.applicat.meuchedet/.MedicinePurchasesListScreen
10-21 14:43:58.698: W/ActivityManager(1156): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40553fb8 com.applicat.meuchedet/.MedicinePurchasesListScreen}
10-21 14:44:07.308: W/ActivityManager(1156): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40553fb8 com.applicat.meuchedet/.MedicinePurchasesListScreen}
10-21 14:44:08.708: W/ActivityManager(1156): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{409a4ad8 com.applicat.meuchedet/.PrescriptionsListScreen}
```

MenuScreenActivity is the "B" described above.
PrescriptionsListScreen is the "C".
MedicinePurchasesListScreen is the "D".

I added Log commands in D and it does not reach the "onSaveInstanceState" and "onRestoreInstanceState" methods there.

It does seem to make it back to "C" and into its "onRestore" but with rubbish in the bundle. The view structure is not reconstructed.

I get a NullPointerException in "C" because of the fact that the views are not being reconstructed.

To be sure they aren't I added Log commands that print out the complete tree of the current contents of the view.
Before the "onSave" in C it is ok but after the "onRestore" is executed it is empty.

I am definitely calling through to the "super" in "onSave" and "onRestore".

============================================

Edit:
I logged the contents of the savedInstance on at the end of "onSaveInstanceState" and at the start of "onRestoreInstanceState".

This is what I got.

Save:

```
onSaveInstanceState -    Bundle = Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[{android:views=android.util.SparseArray@40730568}], SavedData=com.applicat.meuchedet.MedicinePurchasesListScreen$MedicinePurchasesListScreen_SaveData@407c4ae0}]. contents = [android:viewHierarchyState, SavedData]
```

Restore:

```
onRestoreInstanceState - Bundle = Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=5368], SavedData=com.applicat.meuchedet.PrescriptionsListScreen$PrescriptionsListScreen_SaveData@40563c60}]. contents = [android:viewHierarchyState, SavedData]
```

As can be seen, the "viewHierarchyState" bundle is not the same.
However, in other screens where things work it is.

The only difference between this and other screens is that the screen content here is a TabHost.
However, this is NOT a TabActivity. It is a normal Activity with the XML having the tabhost and it being set up in the code.